# Pass Java agent parameters from Gradle to Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I need to pass spring-instrument.jar absolute path via gradle to Idea, for IT tests. Then, I will assign this env. var as -javaagent

I have below dependencies:

```
dependencies {
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-instrument:4.3.2.RELEASE'
runtime 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9'
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:4.3.2.RELEASE'
}
```

[image]
I just simply get instrument agent path, and give this to VM Options.
Also, I can not use `environment` in gradle since `agentsToEnvironment` can not be a `Test type` task.